# Probability of getting n heads when n is very large

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

How to show that the probability of getting n heads when 2n times coin is toss is very small?
Moreover, how to show that the probability of more than n heads is close to 0.5?

Comment: Is the coin fair? Are you familiar with the binomial distribution?

Comment: yes, the coin is fair. I am familiar with binomial distribution as well as stirling approximation. However, I am not getting any concrete answer.

Comment: I think Stirling's formula should do the trick. For the second part, if $X$ denotes the number of heads, then $\mathbb{P}(X<n)+\mathbb{P}(X=n)+\mathbb{P}(X>n)=1$, $\mathbb{P}(X<n)=\mathbb{P}(X>n)$, and $\mathbb{P}(X=n)$ is small.

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thanks. I didn't give it a thought this way.

Comment: Are you dealing with the probability of getting exactly $n$ heads in the first portion of the problem or getting at least $n$ heads?

Comment: yes, getting exactly n heads.

Comment: @WillFisher clearly it is the probability of getting exactly, since that is the probability which is small as $n$ grows large.  At least $n$ heads approaches $0.5$ which is not "small" in the context of probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the random variable counting the number of times heads occurs in $2n$ independent flips of a fair coin.

Via the binomial distribution:

$Pr(X=k) = \dfrac{\binom{2n}{k}}{2^{2n}}$

More specifically, $Pr(X=n) = \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$

Via [stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), $\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ as $n$ grows large, so the above simplifies to:

> $Pr(X=n)\sim \dfrac{4^n/\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\to 0$ as $n$ grows large.

For the second half, as mentioned in comments above, we recognize that $Pr(X<n)=Pr(X>n)$ due to the coin being fair and that $Pr(X<n)+Pr(X=n)+Pr(X>n)=1$ as the three events form a partition of the sample space.

> From the previous part, since $Pr(X=n)\to 0$ and the observation, this implies that $2Pr(X<n)\to 1$, and thus $Pr(X<n)\to 0.5$